# CiviXero extension broken after upgrade to 2.1.0

Tags: wordpress, civixero

I'm using version CiviCRM 5.57.0 and have just upgraded CiviXero to 2.1.0

CiviXero has fallen over and prevented Cron from running. When I run Cron I get the following errors...

```
Notice: Undefined variable: nvpreq in /wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/nz.co.fuzion.civixero/packages/Xero/Xero.php on line 255
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Civi\Api4\AccountContact' not found in /wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/nz.co.fuzion.civixero/CRM/Civixero/Contact.php:96

Stack trace:
#0 /wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/nz.co.fuzion.civixero/api/v3/Civixero/Contactpush.php(50): CRM_Civixero_Contact->push(Array)
#1 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_civixero_contactpush(Array)
#2 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(158): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke(Array)
#3 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(81): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest(Array)
#4 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php(22): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe('Civixero', 'contactpush', Array)
#5 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(131): civicrm_api('Civixero', 'contactpush', Array)
#6 in /wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/nz.co.fuzion.civixero/CRM/Civixero/Contact.php on line 96
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to update [AccountSync](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.accountsync) extensions as well.

There isn't a [recent released](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civi-account-sync) version available but you can download the latest code from [here](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.accountsync/archive/refs/heads/master.zip).

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: That makes complete sense, thanks.